# Convert string date to date object Java

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert my string date: '*Saturday 19th May*' to the date object. I have looked at other examples and tried to use `SimpleDateFormat`. The method I have at the moment is:

```
     DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE/dd/MM" , Locale.ENGLISH);
```

However, I get this error when trying to format it.

```
     java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Saturday 19th May" 
           (at offset 8)
```

Does anyone know the correct way to format this String?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your date string match the format `EE/dd/MM`?

Comment: Besides the fact that your string format doesn't match the parsing format, how do you expect a date like "Saturday 19th May" to be parsed when it could occur in any number of years?

Comment: @JoeC No, have changed it now but still do not really understand

Comment: @kshetline I do not need the year in my dates, does it need to have one to parse it?

Comment: Yes, it needs a year because a date object can't help but have a year, the result of parsing can't be ambiguous.

Comment: "19th" is probably what's tripping it up since I don't believe `dd` handles `th`.  It'd probably work if you stated `Saturday 19 May`.

Comment: @kshetline I did not know that, thank you.

Comment: @Makoto okay i'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: @Makoto you was correct! thank you!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: If you just want May 19 without a year (and hence without a day-of-week even though there is one in the string), you need [the `MonthDay` class of java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
String str = "Saturday 17th March 2018";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(format.parse(str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(st|nd|rd|th)", "")));
```

Comment: Yeah I literally just did this, marked your answer as correct as it's pretty much the same. Thanks